# php preg_replace wrong charset or encoding

Tags: php, regex, character-encoding

I've this simple code:

```
function getCleanText($rawText) //removes doublespace and punctuation
{
    return strtolower(preg_replace("/[\s\t]+/u", " ", 
        preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z1-9àèéìòù]+/u", " ", $rawText)));
}

echo getCleanText("uscì"). " uscì <br>";
```

the function just removes punctuation and double spaces.
Why i've this output?

```
usc�� uscì
```

I mean "uscì" doesn't have any punctuation and the function is supposed to return it as it is without modification. Still i've problem with all accented letters. The web page is encoded in UTF-8. if i try with utf_encode like this

```
return utf8_encode(strtolower(preg_replace("/[\s\t]+/u", " ", 
        preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z1-9àèéìòù]+/u", " ", $rawText))));
```

the output is

```
uscã¬ uscì
```

any ideas? Where i can find some documentation to understand my error?

Comment: Not getting that behavior here, https://3v4l.org/n652S; https://eval.in/459413. You sure the input is as you have it here? Your file is utf8?

Comment: with or without ini_set the result is the  same. 
The source file is encoded in utf-8.

Comment: did you check `return strtolower(preg_replace("/[\s\t]+/u", " ", 
        preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z1-9àèéìòù]+/u", " ", utf8_encode($rawText))));` ?

Comment: actually the accented characters work fine: echo "uscì" outputs as expected. the @JulioSoares solution outputs `usc uscì`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `mb_strtolower`, rather than just `strtolower` resolves the problem in my tests. I assume it's a `php.ini` configuration issue that's means it works OK for some people and not others.

Comment: `return mb_strtolower(preg_replace("/[\s\t]+/u", " ", preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z1-9àèéìòù]+/u", " ", $rawText)), 'UTF-8');` works! For some reason i was sure that the problem was in the preg_replace function. Thanks!